# Use yargs with Typescript

Tags: typescript, yargs

I don't understand when I abstract `options` to a variable (or even import from another file), Typescript complains with:

```
Argument of type '{ exclude: { type: string; required: boolean; description: string; default: never[]; alias: string; }; someOtherFlag: { type: string; required: boolean; description: string; default: never[]; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: Options; }'.
  Property 'exclude' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ type: string; required: boolean; description: string; default: never[]; alias: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string" | "number" | "boolean" | "array" | "count" | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

```
import * as yargs from 'yargs';

const options = {
  exclude: {
    type: 'array',
    required: false,
    description: 'Files to exclude',
    default: [],
    alias: 'e'
  },
  someOtherFlag: {
    type: 'array',
    required: false,
    description: 'Another example flag'
    default: []
  }
};

// throws Typescript error
const cliOptions = yargs.options(options).argv;
```

Answer (score 4):

Do one of the following (first is using [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)):

```
const options = {...} as const 

// or 
const options = {
  exclude: { type: "array"  as "array", ...},
  someOtherFlag: { type: "array" as "array", ...}
}
```

Explanation:

Your `options` literal passed to `yargs.options(options)` seems to be fine, when looking at its type [declaration](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/yargs/index.d.ts#L411).

There is one important point, why it doesn't work in the current form: `options` literal type gets widened. As a consequence, `type: 'array'` becomes `type: string`. `yargs.options` expects a [string literal](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/yargs/index.d.ts#L674) for `type`, so here it blows up.

Mentioned type widening basically happens because of an [immutability check](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) and lack of explicit type, if you want to read more on this topic.